# Retrieving Events from iCal into my iOS application

Tags: objective-c, icalendar, eventkit

hello stack'y people !

i'm looking for any tutorial to import events from iCal into an iOS application ( ? )

Cannot find anything i only find the other way round i mean add event from iOS application into iCal... :(

I found this nice tutorial : `http://neilang.com/entries/using-eventkit-in-ios/`
i know that i have to use EventKit.framework but it doesn't help me to start well...

Do you have any idea of a Tutorial for that ? wil be a pleasure to use it ;)

have a good day/morning/evening/afternoon. ;)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry BUT ! i found the answer ;)

here is the code :

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate   = [NSDate distantFuture];
    //NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                 endDate:endDate
                                                               calendars:nil];

    NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        /* iOS Settings > Privacy > Calendars > MY APP > ENABLE | DISABLE */
        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if ( granted )
             {
                 NSLog(@"User has granted permission!");
                 NSLog(@"events %@", events);

             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"User has not granted permission!");
             }
         }];
    }
```

this is asking the user to allow the application to get the calendar ( all of them by default )

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
```